# React: Scroll Aligment Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have components which have dropdown. When dropdown is opened, I need to bring the scroll to the center if scroll occurs.

Details:
https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-pine-k2dzx?file=/src/App.js

What i want:
[image]

Comment: is the button meant to be a part of the scroll container or not?

Answer (score 1):

I have taken a stab with the following assumptions

- your items are contained within a "scrollcontainer" div (like many list items would be contained within a container)
- the button resides outside of this "scrollContainer".

The interesting part with this siutation, is requiring the ref to actually determine and set the scroll top position, which is only available after show is true, and the component has mounted. Assigning a ref value wont cause the component to rerender, so we need to add a callback which will provide us with a ref, and provide us with a concrete way to interact with the ref as soon as its available.

for this purpose, I created a function as follows

```
  const refAssignCallback = (ref) => {
    if (!containerRef.current && ref) {
      //the containerRef is currently null, ref available = mounted.
      containerRef.current = ref;
      var element = containerRef.current;
      var scrollHeight = element.scrollHeight;
      var clientHeight = element.getBoundingClientRect().height;

      //explicitly set the scrollTop position of the scrollContainer
      containerRef.current.scrollTop = (scrollHeight - clientHeight) / 2;
    } else {
      //otherwise just assign/unassigned
      containerRef.current = ref;
    }
  };
```

this function is assigned to the ref attribute of your scroll container div. When it mounts, a ref is provided to this function and we can react appropriately.

it first checks to see if the containerRef is currently null, because then we know its opening for the first time and we only want to programatically set the scroll position the first time it opens, and not again. Any other time we can just assign the containerRef to the recieved ref.

once we have the ref, we programatically set the scrollTop position of the scrollContainer to the half way position.

Full code below:

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

    const App = () => {
      const containerRef = useRef();
      const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    
      //fired when the box is mounted
      const refAssignCallback = (ref) => {
        if (!containerRef.current) {
          containerRef.current = ref;
          var element = containerRef.current;
          var scrollHeight = element.scrollHeight;
          var clientHeight = element.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    
          containerRef.current.scrollTop = (scrollHeight - clientHeight) / 2;
        } else {
          //otherwise just assign/unassign
          containerRef.current = ref;
        }
      };
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>HEY</button>
      {isOpen && (
        <div
          ref={refAssignCallback}
          style={{ height: "300px", overflowY: "auto" }}
          name="scrollContainer"
        >
          <div
            style={{
              width: 300,
              height: 1500,
              backgroundColor: "lightGray",
              marginTop: 20
            }}
          />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[CodesandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-cdn-kz82k?file=/src/App.js:0-1173)

Comment: Is overflowY necessary? I want to use it as hook and use it on all my dropdown components. Sometimes there is no need for scrolling.

Comment: in that case, you can set "overflowY" to "auto". The scrollbar wont appear unless required. I updated the answer to reflect this

Comment: Do we have to give the height in container? Can't get the height of dropdown that opens automatically? Thanks but my problem is not completely solved because having height spoils the screen.

Comment: How do you achieve a scroll container without limiting the height of the container? there needs to be overflow.

Comment: In sandbox example, gray box have already been overflow. I need to take his height.

Comment: In your sandbox example, the actual <html> tag is acting as the container. It is providing the scrollbars and handling the overflow. Is that really what you want? This is even outside of the <div> root element the App is rendered to. Inspect the DOM using chrome dev tools on your sandbox and you will see what I mean.

Comment: is this more what you are looking for? [CodeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-driscoll-u42bh?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you very much but I have one more question. Can we get the current position of the scroll? Because while I'm like this, if the scroll is long and I open the dropdown at the bottom, it will throw it in the middle of the page. I think adding +20 margin to Scroll's current position will solve the problem.